# How can I determine the variable value in this CSS?

Tags: css, variables

I inspected the Google User Icon and found this code:

```
img.yt-img-shadow {
    display: block;
    margin-left: var(--yt-img-margin-left, auto);
    margin-right: var(--yt-img-margin-right, auto);
    max-height: var(--yt-img-max-height, none);
    max-width: var(--yt-img-max-width, 100%);
    border-radius: var(--yt-img-border-radius, none);
}
```

How can I determine how this is interpreted particularly the `var()`?

Thanks.

Comment: try to look at the computed value in the browser inspector

Comment: these are called CSS variables,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS has been developing at a rapid rate so that now you can declare variables with out having to use a library like LESS.

See the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for CSS "custom properties" which is just another name for variables.

Here is the simplicity of it:

Define:

```
element {
  --main-bg-color: brown;
}
```

Use:

```
element {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--yt-img-margin-left
--yt-img-margin-right
```

**Values for these variables will be defined in the css files. If you search the CSS file you'll get values for variables.**

[It'll look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6qV5.png)

Comment: Are variables being used in CSS now or is Google using a library like LESS?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties